# Refreshing and redirecting page after clicking button

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, firebase

The problem :

After clicking "Post now" modal with filled form still shows up and if to click "post now" again it adds the same data again and again.

I'd like to make that after all form is filled in and button is clicked, page refreshes and goes to the link with description of prediction.

```
Prediction.createPrediction($scope.prediction).then(function(ref) {
            $toaster.pop('success', 'Prediction posted successfully.');
            $scope.prediction = {
                player1: '',
                player2: '',
                winner: '',
                venue: '',
                date: '',
                round: '',
                description: '',
                odd: '',
                score: '',
                status: 'open',
                gravatar: '',
                name: '',
                poster: ''
            };
            $location.path('/browse/' + ref.key());
        });
```

Link to the application: https://sportpredictions.firebaseapp.com/#/
(Posting predictions is available only for signed in users)

Source code on GitHub: https://github.com/NiR-IT/tennispredictions (scripts/services/prediction.js, scripts/controllers/prediction.js, views/partials/post.html).

Comment: Are we to assume this isn't working? What is happening?

Comment: Page is not refreshing after clicking the button submit in modal. So if manually close the modal and click button "post prediction" again, there will be modal with the same, already filled in form .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: add a `name="postForm"` attribute to your form. This will make it accessible in your controller via `$scope.postForm` and then you can call `$scope.postForm.$setPristine()` which should reset everything on the form - including any validation errors, etc.

P.S. Really nice looking app!

Comment: Where exactly I should put $scope.postForm.$setPristine()? 
And also appears error in console " $toaster is not defined " (when I click submit button".

Thanks, Lex :)

Comment: You're injecting `toaster` into your controller so you need to call it without the `$`. I would put the call to `$setPristine()` right after your toaster message. You can probably get rid of the rest of that code.

Comment: So thing is that now happens the same, if to put jquery code

$('#Button').click(function() {

    location.reload();

});

Page reloads after clicking the button, but database is not updated with new prediction too ;(

Comment: Wait, why are you using jQuery to reload the page? Sorry, I'm totally confused now. I thought you were redirecting with Angular. I strongly recommend not mixing jQuery and Angular if at all possible.

Comment: Oh, I'm not using jQuery in this case, sorry. But I tried and the same happened. So after clicking the button page reloads, yes, but the data (prediction) is not added to the databse. :(

Comment: So the **only** change you made was to call `$scope.postForm.$setPristine()` in the success callback of your `Prediction.createPrediction()` method and now it's not saving to the database? I have no idea then. The `$scope.postForm.$setPristine()` should be getting called after all the database stuff happens so I'm not sure why it would be affecting that.